# Getting the same random number repeatedly in C++

Tags: c++

Although i wrote srand(time(0)); it still producing the same number. Also ctime and cstdlib defined. Is there anyone help me to figure out this problem? Thanks.

```
    int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    p_matrix_generate(10,3);

    return 0;
}
```

my p_matrix_generate function:

```
void p_matrix_generate(int N, int zero_rate)
{
    srand(time(0));
    vector< vector<double> > p = create_2dvector(N, N);
    int zero_number = ceil(pow(N, 2)*zero_rate / 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            p.at(i).at(j) = generateWeibull(1, 2)*((2 * generateRandomInteger(2, 5)) - 1);
            cout << p.at(i).at(j) << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Weibull function:

```
double generateWeibull(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
{   
    srand(time(0));
    double  temp;
    default_random_engine generator;
    weibull_distribution<double> distribution(lower_bound, upper_bound);
    temp = distribution(generator);
    return temp;
}
```

random number function:

```
int generateRandomInteger(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int random_integer = lower_bound + rand() % (upper_bound + 1);
    return random_integer;
}
```

Comment: First I wrote for each function only. When it didnt work I wrote in main function too. Now I delete all of them except in main and it works. Thank you !

Comment: You call `srand` too frequently. Also, if you are using C++, consider more up-to-date solutions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random